# How can I set a default value for a field in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Suppose I have a model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

Currently I am using the default Django admin to create/edit objects of this type.
How do I remove the field **`b`** from the Django admin so that each object *cannot* be created with a value, and rather will receive a default value of `0000000`?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Set `editable` to `False` and `default` to your default value.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#editable

```
b = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='0000000', editable=False)
```

Also, your `id` field is unnecessary.  Django will add it automatically.

Comment: A default value for a field implies the field to be not editable?

Comment: @PaulBénéteau I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but no, providing a `default` value does not make a field non-editable. `default` is used to set a value in case none was provided. `editable=False` makes the field not show up in forms. OP wanted to _force_ a specific default value, so both options are needed.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use a callable in the default field, such as:

```
b = models.CharField(max_length=7, default=foo)
```

And then define the callable:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 1.8, though the documentation indicates it should. Should `foo()` be a class method?

Comment: You may have to set the `@staticmethod` wrapper around foo function.

Answer (score 27):

You can set the default like this:

```
b = models.CharField(max_length=7,default="foobar")
```

and then you can hide the field with your model's Admin class like this:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ("b")
```