# Can I set a specific default time for a Django datetime field?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a model for events which almost always start at 10:00pm, but may on occasion start earlier/later. To make things easy in the admin, I'd like for the time to default to 10pm, but be changeable if needed; the date will need to be set regardless, so it doesn't need a default, but ideally it would default to the current date.

I realize that I can use datetime.now to accomplish the latter, but is it possible (and how) to I set the time to a specific default value?

Update: I'm getting answers faster than I can figure out which one(s) does what I'm trying to accomplish...I probably should have been further along with the app before I asked. Thanks for the help in the meantime!

Comment: I'm getting 'TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default''. Any ideas? Using a forms.Form instead of a model form. forms.TimeField(default=dt.time(16, 0), widget=forms.TimeInput)

Comment: did you fix it please ? if yes , can share the code please

Answer (score 23):

From the Django documents for `Field.default`:

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.

So do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def default_start_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    start = now.replace(hour=22, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return start if start > now else start + timedelta(days=1)  

class Something(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=default_start_time)
```

Comment: I like how this example uses "tomorrow at 10pm" if the model instance is created after 10pm.

Comment: when you are using `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.now` `now` will be a fixed date, when that is first evaluated. What does that mean? When your server runs for a weak, with `datetime.now()` it will always be the date when the server was started. With using `datetime.now` it will be dynamicely evaluated.

Comment: is it possible to just show the hours and minutes when displayed on the screen rather than show the hours minutes and milliseconds. and rather than use military time, use am and pm... because with what you have above it shows the full time.

Answer (score 18):

in case you're interested into setting default value to [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#timefield): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6754

don't:

```
start = models.TimeField(default='20:00')
```

do instead:

```
import datetime
start = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(16, 00))
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to include datetime.datetime in a `TimeField`. Better to do `start= models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(16, 00))`

Answer (score 4):

`datetime.time(16, 00)` does not work.

Use `datetime.time(datetime.now())` instead if you are trying to get the current time or `datetime.time(your_date_time)`

**Where your_date_time = datetime.datetime object**

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

That's probably what you're looking for.

It's also discussed here: [Default value for field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755857/default-value-for-field-in-django-model)

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

default_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

time_of_visit = models.TimeField(default=default_time)

it will be work fine

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.now()
dt.hour = 22
dt.minute = 0
dt.second = 0
```

Hard to be more specific without context.

Comment: I'm not sure what more context I could give; I just want the person entering the date in to not have to change it to 10:00 every single time they add a new event (but still have the option to change it).
The solution is admittedly simple if there is one; that looks like it might work.