# DateTimeField - separation in admin panel

Tags: python, django, datetime, model

I have two fields `from` and `to`.
In my application (django 1.11.2), sometimes I do not need an hour, I just need the date itself. But validation does not allow me to save the object and asks for hour. Is it possible to somehow separate it or does the date and time always have to be given in the `DateTimeField` field?

```
from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Then you can use `models.DateField()` instead of `models.DateTimeField`

Comment: I believe you have to set the time as well. You can just set it to some default value?

Comment: @N.Ivanov can I set here default hour?

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027516/can-i-set-a-specific-default-time-for-a-django-datetime-field) solution

Comment: You can write a pre_save signal method to add a default hour. If you are never gonna use time use `DateField`