# how to filter posts for a specific hour from its publishing time

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to show my posts for a specific time here is my models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

i want display object for 12 hours after check out for example if we have an object its check out is 14/10/2021 10AM then show that post till 10PM !

i tried it , but didnt work `Booking.objects.filter(check_out__hour=12)`

is it possible please ? thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried timedella in filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Booking.objects.filter(
    check_out__gte=Now()-timedelta(hours=12)
)
```

you can filter further such that no objects with a `check_out` that is later than now are filtered out with a [**`__range`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Booking.objects.filter(
    check_out__range=(Now()-timedelta(hours=12), Now())
)
```

Here `Now()` is the timestamp of the database.

We can also work with the timestamp of the webserver machine with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

Booking.objects.filter(
    check_out__range=(now()-timedelta(hours=12), now())
)
```

Comment: thank you for your response , but it returns all other objects which its checkout greater than current time , i want to only a specific range `check_out+12 hour`then make range between current time with checkout time should be only 12 hours

Comment: @HunarMohammed: then you should filter with a `__range`, see edit (last two code fragments)

Comment: can you take a look at this question please ? i need to set default hour for dateimte field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326480/how-to-set-default-hour-for-my-django-datetimefield