# Django get default value of field if its none

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a legacy database I created a model for it. It looks something like below.

```
class Account(models.Model):
  balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=42, decimal_places=1, default=Decimal('0.0'))
```

When I run the below query I get the `balance field` as `None` insted of using the `default` value on the field.

```
Account.objects.get(pk=1).balance #returns None instead of Decimal(0.0).
```

I would like to get the `default Decimal(0.0)` when legacy balance on SQL database is `NULL`.
Is there a way to tell django orm to give me the default `Decimal(0.0)` instead of `None`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I know we can add custom methods or `@property` and make it a method that returns the balance or the default value but I Also run some other queries like one's below.

```
  Account.objects.values_list('balance') #returns [(1,),(None,),(None,)]
```

Which does not use the default value.

Comment: It might be easier to convert the existing nulls to `0.00`, and change the schema to prevent nulls.

Comment: @Alasdair: I wish but apperantely thats not under my control. :(

Comment: You could try writing a [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-custom-model-fields).

Comment: @Alasdair: I'll give it a try. Thanks, didn't know about custom model fields. Awesome! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to find many different ways to a problem, so you could make a model method:

```
class MyAppModel(models.Model):
    ....

    def get_balace(self):
        return self.balance if self.balance else Decimal(0.0)
    ....
```

Or you could create a Manager (change it to your needs):

```
class MyAppManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyAppManager, self).get_queryset()

    def get_balances(self):
        results = []
        items = self.get_queryset().all()
        for item in items:
            balance = item.balance if item.balance else Decimal(0,0)
            results.append({'pk':item.pk,"balance":balance})
        return results
```

Then in your model:

```
class MyAppModel(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = MyAppManager()
    ...
```

And you query:

```
balances = MyAppModel.objects.get_balances()
```

Comment: This will work, I have a better solution than this by adding `@property` to the method and making it an attribute rather than a method. But it does not help when you run queries like `Account.objects.values_list('balance')`

Comment: The you can create a Manager :)

Comment: I know you had posted the solution before, editing the answer, can you please post it again? Thanks :)

Comment: added, refactor to your needs :)

Comment: This is an old question (and answer), but for the sake of future interested ones, I feel the `self.balance if self.balance else Decimal(0.0)` would be much better solved with an annotation on the queryset, shoving the hard work onto the database instead of python. This will also avoid re-fetching the queryset and returning a strange custom-made object.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a default value on a column merely means that if you don't pass a value the default will be used. Are you explicitly setting the value of this column to `NULL`? If so, then `NULL` will be stored. You haven't provided the query you're using to populate the model.

Consider this table..

```
CREATE TABLE testtbl 
(
    id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    balance NUMERIC NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

Now consider these two insert statements

```
INSERT INTO testtbl (id, balance) VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO testtbl (id) VALUES (2);
```

In the first case, `NULL` will be inserted even though you specified a default. In the second case, `0` will be used for `balance`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes but its a legacy database which already has data inserted with column as `NULL` more over the inserts are not under my control they are done my an ETL.

Comment: So you just want to display `NULL`s as 0.0?

Comment: Yes, but using `django models default`

Comment: Can't you just convert the `None`s to 0's while rendering the template (`{{ value|default_if_none:0.0 }}`). Or if in a view, `if a is None: a = 5`?

Comment: Yes that is an option but its not an elegant one, I'd have to do it in the view level for every model containing decimal field. petkostas has an answer that might be DRY and might handel all models containing Decimal fields. ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can define a custom field class of your own where you override `to_python` method to handle this particular case of yours.
That shall turn something in the lines of following code:

```
import decimal


class DecimalField(models.DecimalField):

  def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
      return decimal.Decimal('0.0')
    super(DecimalField, self).to_python(value)
```

Hope this is somewhere relevant to your problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score -3):

set `editable=False`. Look [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) for further info.

```
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=42, decimal_places=1, default=Decimal('0.0'), editable=False)
```

Comment: For the record, this did not work and didn't make any sense either.

Comment: For the record, when you write `editable=False` it means that it wont show up in the admin panel, and also it will have the default value assigned every time a new record is entered in the DB. The default value that you mention in the model will be assigned to it. Try hard it will start making sense...:-)

Comment: I have no reference of `django-admin` in the question I'm not using it either. I hope you understand what legacy database means. Read and understand the question before answering.

Comment: @Pannu no need to be offended, take it easy. We are here to help each other. Now coming to the comment, i explained that why i wrote editable=False, thats it. If you feel that the answer doesnot address your question you can downvote it. thats how SO works.

Comment: pls have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755857/default-value-for-field-in-django-model