# How to give initial value for every user?

Tags: python, django

***Newly created user have some initial data. -- This feature really I want.***

*Tried*.

I put some sample values into table( `FamilyMember` ) and dumped into `json` format and put that into the name of `initial_data.json` in fixtures directory.

Above working fine when i put below lines in command prompt.

```
python manage.py loaddata --app dashboard initial_data.json
```

But in my case every registered user will get this data instantly they logged in. How do i gonna achieve this ?

Sample json:

```
[  
    {  
        "fields":{  
            "first_name":"Father",
            "last_name":"Father",
            "middle_name":"",
            "birth_state":"",
            "wife":[  

            ],
            "member_image":"",
            "familyname":1,
            "children":[  
                9
            ],
            "sex":"M",
            "preferred_name":"",
            "parents":[  

            ],
            "birth_country":"",
            "birth_date":"1988-11-10",
            "bio_info":"Hi Some Info Here",
            "birth_city":"Country"
        },
        "model":"dashboard.familymember",
        "pk":6
    },
]
```

Comment: How about adding a default value directly into your model?

Comment: Me too thought about that idea because manytomany relation with fixture really gonna hard. Can you provide me some of example how to go with it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link: [Default value for field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755857/default-value-for-field-in-django-model). Why do you have a `pk` attribute? Django automatically creates an id.

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Country', editable=False)
    ....
```

Comment: Instead of `OnetoOneField`, use `ManytoManyField`. Replace `User` to the class that you want to have a relationship with.