# django many to many save admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a model like :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ManyToManyField(Type, blank=True)
```

Here from admin I am adding MyModel.

What I want is if the type is not provided while saving then I want the type to be as default like `Teacher`

type `Teacher` has not been created. If the type is not provided I want to create the type and assign it if the type is not provided

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/755863/3270800

Comment: I am talking about many to many field... the example is for char field

Comment: customize the save() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related)'s example, you can override `save_model` like this:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        if not form.cleaned_data['type']:
            type, created = Type.objects.get_or_create(name="Teacher")
            form.cleaned_data['type'] = [type]
        form.save_m2m()
        for formset in formsets:
             self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
```

Comment: I tried this but type is not being added to obj. MyModel is being saved but type is not added to it..

Comment: Hi @aryan, I have updated the answer. Please check if it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you it works and I have did it already.. but thank you for your effort.. I have also done with same process as yours