# Confused about how to make Django model field optional

Tags: django, django-models

I have an 'address' field in my Django model that I want to be optional:

```
class Home(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I want this to be an optional field in my database but I didn't set "null=True" because the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) says

"Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL."

However, when I create a Home object with this command:

```
Home.objects.create(city='Chicago')
```

I get an error:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column 'address' violates not-null constraint.
```

Shouldn't I add "null=True" to the address field despite what the docs say in order to make it optional?  If not, how should it be declared so that I can create new Home objects without raising this error?

Comment: May you want to set 'default' value?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: Also see answers for this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755857/default-value-for-field-in-django-model

Comment: I did.  It's set to 'None'.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Just leave out the `default` and the default value will be the empty string.

Comment: 'None' is a NULL constraint obviously. Just assign empty string to default value. I'm not agree with Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you not always add address you need to add

```
null= True
```

because default is set to None but the DB isn't set to accept null's

Comment: I don't understand why the documentation says what it does without addressing this issue so I'm just going to set "null=True" as I usually do.

Answer (score 5):

You should get rid of `default=None`, otherwise, you can just use `default=''`

Comment: I think that this is the best way to do it, because it is consistent with how Django represents empty CharFields.

Comment: When I make this change and examine my PostgreSQL database table schema, it still says that the address field is "not null".

Comment: Did you run 'manage.py makemigrations' and 'manage.py migrate'?

Comment: Ok great, but is this new issue an error, or it just says the field is not null?

Comment: When doing \d, the database schema just says that the address field is "not null"  It's not a database error.

Comment: Sounds like it's working - `not null` would make sense, considering that `default=''` is an empty string (and therefor not null)